# Sonarqube logout issue with SSO Authentication as HTTP headers

Tags: sonarqube

I have a problem with logout API. I use SSO Authentication as HTTP headers mode. I can login successfully but when I want to logout. It keeps me login in Sonarqube server.

Sonarqube version 6.7

Answer (score 1):

By definition, when you're using the HTTP authentication header, the login/logout is delegated to your reverse proxy, or any tool you're using to set the HTTP headers.
Please have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/HTTP+headers) for more info about this feature.

Comment: Thank for your message. I am using mod_auth_cas.so. Here is my reverse proxy config. 

`
CASLoginURL https://signin.xxx.com/cas/default/user/cas/login
CASValidateURL https://signin.xxxx.com/cas/serviceValidate
<Location />
CASAuthNHeader X-Forwarded-Login
Authtype CAS
require valid-user
</Location>
   ProxyPass /   http://127.0.0.1:9000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/sonar.xx.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/sonar.xx-gtc.com-access_log" 
</VirtualHost>
`